# Navigation Bar - differentiation

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar which works great. The only problem is, that I created one link and I can't see the half of the link.

Can anybody help me???

[image]

HTML:

```
    <header id="main-header">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <table id="header-nav-table">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="header-nav-table-button">LINK</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

section {
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.main-nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4682B4; /* steelblue */
}

.main-nav-addClass {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
/*  top: -1px;
    left: -1px;*/
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4682B4; /* steelblue */
}

.header-nav-table-button {
    margin-left: 1200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    border: 1px solid #4682B4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #4682B4;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header-nav-table-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ECF0F1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4682B4;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, what's the "hlf of the link"?  Are you talking about the `href`?

Comment: as per your HTML and CSS it seems everything ok. as you have set the margin-left 1200px (?) in .header-nav-table-button

Comment: I only can use 1200px, but I want to use 80%

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bit of padding to the actual table, like so

```
#header-nav-table {
    padding-top:1%;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p5pejgqg/1/

Comment: If you check the jsfiddle, you'll see that the button is moved down slightly.   If you remove the table padding, it will move up off the display area just a bit as in your screen shot.    Do you have another element that the <header> is inside of?  You may need to add the padding higher up the HTML tree depending on what your full code looks like.